# Inequality for lower bound of polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to understand the justification for the inequalities in the proof of Lemma 3.1.3 described [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Book%3A_Linear_Algebra_(Schilling%2C_Nachtergaele_and_Lankham)/03%3A_3._The_fundamental_theorem_of_algebra_and_factoring_polynomials/3.01%3A_The_Fundamental_Theorem_of_Algebra).

The lemma is trying to prove that for any polynomial function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ there exits a point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f|$ attains a minimum value in $\mathbb{R}$

The proof proceeds by letting

$f = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots + a_n z^n$ where $a^n \neq 0$ and $z \neq 0$

and

$A = max\{|a_0|, \cdots |a_n|\}$

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
|f(z)| &=& |a_n| |z|^n \left|1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \frac{1}{z} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{a_n} \frac{1}{z^n}\right|\\
       &\geq& |a_n| |z|^n \left(1 - \frac{A}{|a_n|} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|z|^k} \right) \\
\end{eqnarray}

The *justification for this inequality is not clear* to me.  In particular the change from summation to subtraction is not obvious.  If this is an application of the reverse triangle inequality, shouldn't the parenthesis be replaced by modulus?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You apply the reverse triangle inequality first, then apply the “normal” triangle inequality to the second term.

Comment: They used $|a+b|=|a-(-b)|\geq |a|-|-b|=|a|-|b|$, with $a=1$ and $b=\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\frac{1}{z}+...+\frac{a_0}{a_n}\frac{1}{z^n}$. The inequality $|a-(-b)|\geq |a|-|-b|$ is equivalent to $|a-(-b)|+|-b|\geq |(a-(-b))+(-b)|=|a|$, which is the triangle inequality $|x|+|y|\geq |x+y|$ applied to $x=a-(-b)$ and $y=-b$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|a - (-b)| \geq | |a| - |-b| | $ ?

Comment: @BThomas That form is deduced by combining the one that I wrote with $|a-(-b)|=|(-b)-a|\geq |-b|-|a|=-(|a|-|-b|)$. Since $|a-(-b)|\geq |a|-|-b|$ and also $|a-(-b)|\geq -(|-b|-|a|)$, then $|a-(-b)|\geq||a|-|-b||$. It is also true, but it is more information than needed.